# Impossible Error: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, azure, azure-mobile-services

I've looked at the other solutions regarding this error, but I believe my problem is different. As they do not work.

I have a Azure App Services backend. It's using ASP.NET and Entity.
For some strange reason, I'm unable to insert a new entry into one of my tables.
It's only this one table, nothing has changed on it. I understand why this error is thrown under normal circumstances, but nothing is changing by the time I save my changes.

Something as simple as this, is throwing the error:

```
var client = new Client() { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), CompanyID = "guid-fk-in-other-table" };
context.Clients.Add(client);
context.SaveChanges();
```

When I step through with the debugger, the context.Clients.Add(client); line takes really long to execute and the output window shows a bunch of unhelpful exceptions such as:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' in EntityFramework.dll
```

The table schema is identical to my DataObject. I'm getting desperate and have no idea how to diagnose from here. Any help is appreciated beyond belief!

Comment: Do you have a trigger that might be rolling back changes on that table?  There is a few possibilities here...perhaps locking...the error is a generic "row didn't update" in my experience.

Comment: No triggers on the table other than the one Mobile Apps creates (insert/update/delete updating the "UpdatedAt" timestamp.

Comment: Most I can do is add troubleshoot tips, unfortunately it's a vague error.  I believe it's trying to say "nothing was inserted" with the error returned there. is Guid.NewGuid().ToString() returning a valid value (try hardcoding to id = 10101,   CompanyID = "guid-fk-in-other-table".  If that works, then that newguid function is at fault)?  Can you insert through a different tool (table might be locked by someone else)?  Is there a FK being violated that would prevent an insert (admitadely this should return a more detailed error if this was the case)?  Sorry for no definite answer

Answer (score 0):

Well, after weeks of debugging, finally figured this one out.

There's row-level security implemented on this table. For some reason, Entity is unable to add a row if the current user doesn't pass the access predicate. I'm able to insert rows directly through SQL though without passing the policy, so this contributed to the confusion.
I guess Entity attempts to read the entry?

Anyway,
I then deleted the policy and things worked as they should. The reason they worked before, is because the calling app had cached credentials, satisfying the security policy. Once I cleared them, the issue came up.
There was absolutely nothing I could find in debugger exceptions that would have led me to this conclusion, an exception pointing out the security policy was at fault would have been welcome.